# Django manager return all entries for today - DateTimeField

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-managers

How would I make a manager that will return all the entries in a model with todays date, the model field is a datetime field, not a datefield?

```
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class ValidEntryManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(ValidEntryManager, self).get_query_set().filter(timestamp__gte=datetime.today(), timestamp__lte=datetime.today())

allowed_entries = ValidEntryManager()
```

This is what I tried, but it returns 0 objects, there should be.

> print Entries.allowed_entries.all() >>>> []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try setting both dates to midnight:

```
class ValidEntryManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        today = datetime.today()
        start_date = datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day)
        end_date = datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day+1)
        return super(ValidEntryManager, self).get_query_set().filter(timestamp__gte=start_date, timestamp__lte=end_date)
```

Comment: Much better to use `end_date = start_date + time delta(days=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class ValidEntryManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(ValidEntryManager, self).get_query_set().filter(timestamp__range=(datetime.now(), datetime.now()- timedelta(days=1))
```

Comment: This will possibly catch some entries from previous day as well

Answer (score 0):

No need for a manager for such a simple task.

```
from datetime import date

...

@staticmethod
def get_for_today():
    today = date.today()
    return Entry.objects.filter(date_time__day=today.day,
                                date_time__month=today.month,
                                date_time__year=today.year,)
```

And then just:

```
>>> Entry.get_for_today()
```